# Was Haftarah prophesied on Motzei Shabbos?

Tags: sources-mekorot, nevua-prophecy, navi-prophets, haftarah

Shlomo Carlebach, in the YouTube video for his song נחמו נחמו עמי, claims that it is well known that 'according to our tradition', the prophet prophesied the הפטרה for a given week on the Motzei Shabbos of that parsha.

1:12 in this video [נחמו נחמו עמי - Carlebach](https://youtu.be/5dptj7zzIig)

Is there any source for this in pre-Carlebachian Jewish scholarship? 
Earliest source that can be found is best...

Comment: While I enjoy SC ztz"l's music and his stories, I'm skeptical that the concept of any haftarah was prophesied by any prophet at all. From what I recall from Tal. Megilla, the majority of haftarot are *divrei sofrim*, whom I believe lived long after the prophets. Even if my chronology is incorrect. the haftarot are not "uniform" - Ashkenazim and Sefardim, among other groups have different haftarot each week. Is Carlebach suggesting that the prophets made up a separate haftarah for each of these groups? In short, Carelbach gave a nice story on this one IMO.

Comment: @danf plus you can read a different haftara if you need to e.g. if the only navi you have is the wrong book and you don't have a Chumash with haftarot on the back.